# How do I correctly (import (srfi :42)) in Chez scheme?

Tags: import, scheme, chez-scheme

(System: centos 7, 64 bits)

I am attempting to import srfi-42 into my program. This is the
first srfi in Chez Scheme for me.

The srfi lib is at:

```
/home/cecilm/play/ChezScheme/chez-srfi/srfi
```

I added this dir to my .emacs :

```
(setenv "CHEZSCHEMELIBDIRS"
    (concat
      "."    ":"
      (getenv "$HOME") /play/ChezScheme/chez-srfi" ":"
      (getenv "PATH")))
```

In emacs, geiser starts chez. emacs seems to know about this dir:

```
> (library-directories)
(("/home/cecilm/play/ChezScheme/chez-srfi"
   .
   "/home/cecilm/play/ChezScheme/chez-srfi"))
```

The repl seems to import srfi-42:

```
> (import (srfi :42))
> (list-ec (: i 5) (* i i))

Exception: attempt to reference out-of-context identifier error
```

I thought "i" was a problem, so I defined "i" in a let:

```
> (let ((i 0)) (list-ec (: i 5) (* i i)))

Exception: attempt to reference out-of-context identifier error
```

What do I need to do to actually use an import? This is the first time
I have used any imports in Chez Scheme.

Does "list-ec" need a qualifier?

I obtained the srfi's from [git](https://github.com/dharmatech/chez-srfi.git)  Is this a "standard"?
Is there a more "official" repo for Chez scheme?

Comment: Problem resolved. See: https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/issues/156

Comment: you can answer your own question. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer